# JSON to PHP Array error

Tags: php, json, api

i am having trouble getting a JSON file to a php-array.

i got a json-file as response from an api (request done with curl)
and want to make an array out of it but it won't work.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class modExpose{
public static function getFunction($id){

//In my code i am "preparing" the request here


// ***********  cURL
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$qry_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $response;
}
}


$id = $_GET['id'];
$data = modExpose::getFunction($id);
$array = json_decode($data,true);
print_r($array);

?>
```

the print_r function only delivers: 1. (same does the var_dump() function).
I also tried adding html_entity_decode() but the problem still remains.

Thank's for helping!

Comment: what's the response json ? and check out the response of [json_last_error](http://php.net/json_last_error)

Comment: i don't want to post it here because it contains customers data but it is a valid json file and if i don't add print_r() or var_dump() at the end safari shows a highlighted and perfect formated json file.

Comment: @Philipp, that's a weak reason not to provide an MVCE. You could replace all of the personally identifiable information with placeholder information while maintaining the structure of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably because the return value of your [`curl_exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) call is `true` on success and that is all you are returning from your method.

If you want to get the data that was returned by the curl call, you need to set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url.$qry_str);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
// Return the result on success
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
// Now response will contain the results of your curl call
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Apart from that I assume you have checked the variables that seem to be undefined in your example code.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!!
It would have taken me years to figure that out.